# How do you get your local repo to match the server?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-fetch

```
    b-c-d     <= branch-1         On GitHub                                     
   /                                                                            
  a-e-f-g     <= branch-2                                                       
      \                                                                         
       h-i    <= branch-3                                                       
                                                                                
                                                                                
    b-c-d     <= branch-1         On local                                      
   /                                                                            
  a-e-f-g     <= branch-2
```

If I'm on Branch-1 and do a "git pull origin branch-3"  I end up with

```
    b-c-d-h-i <= branch-1         On local                                      
   /                                                                            
  a-e-f-g     <= branch-2
```

If I'm on Branch-2 and do a "git pull origin branch-3"  I end up with

```
    b-c-d     <= branch-1         On local                                      
   /                                                                            
  a-e-f-g-h-i <= branch-2
```

What command do I issue to get branch-3 to be attached to commit  " f "  as seen on GitHub version ?

Comment: Question: Does `branch-3` already exist in GitHub?  Or, are you trying to create a `branch-3` which looks like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git pull` is really `git fetch` followed by `git merge`.

When you run `git pull branch-3` while on branch-1 or branch-2, you are telling git to merge branch-3 into branch-1 or branch-2.

branch-3 likely already exists on your local repo as a remote tracking branch (you can see it by running `git branch --list --all`). You can create a local branch that tracks the remote branch using a git shortcut: `git checkout branch-3`. This command notes that remotes/origin/branch-3 exists and assumes you want to create a new local branch to track the remote branch.

Comment: Excellent.  I didn't know I could checkout a remote tracking branch.  I knew it existed (I could see it with "git branch -a")  but because it wasn't a local branch I didn't think it was possible.  In fact I did try a "git merge origin/branch-3" but it added in on top of my current branch.  Thx again

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you can do a simple `git pull`, then `git checkout branch-3`.